# Ngx_webstorage retrieve value is null

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 with `ngx-webstorage`.

First I install `npm install --save ngx-webstorage`.

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Ng2Webstorage} from 'ngx-webstorage';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        Ng2Webstorage,
        ],
    bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

and here is my another component.ts

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LocalStorageService} from 'ngx-webstorage';

@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: `
        <section>{{attribute}}</section>
        <section><button (click)="add()">Add</button></section>
        <section><button (click)="retrieveValue()">Retrieve</button></section>
    `,
})
export class FooComponent {

    attribute;

    constructor(private storage:LocalStorageService) {}

    add(){
      this.storage.store('boundValue',"Test");
    }

    retrieveValue() {
      this.attribute = this.storage.retrieve('boundValue');
      console.log(this.attribute);
    }

}
```

When i click `Add` button i store the `boundvalue`.and I click the `Retrieve` Button retrieve the `'boundvalue'`.

It's work.But i refresh my web page.The `boundvalue` is null.

I need boundvalue is everytime. How can I do this?

Comment: `[angularjs]` != `[angular]`. Be careful with tags! ;-)

Comment: When you refresh and click, is the boundValue null?

Answer (score 0):

When I've faced similar issues it's because I was clearing the storage somewhere unintentionally. Run a search in your project for "this.storage.clear", or look at every component where you have imported ngx-webstorage and see if you clear your storage anywhere.